# Connect Spring Boot to SQL Server Express

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sql-server-express

I try to connect my gradle Spring Boot Application to a running SQL Server Express installation.

My configuration is

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;InstanceName=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=testDB;integratedsecurity=true
    spring.datasource.username=SpringBootUser
    spring.datasource.password=testPassword123
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
```

The build.grade has those dependencies:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
}
```

But all i get are those messages:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to
>   create requested service
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to
>   DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an application.properties in your classpath. it seems your application couldn't load your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

After i downloaded a sqljdbc_auth.dll and put it into the PATH the Application ran.